# Configurar botão para abrir o console do navegador (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, aplicação-web

Bom dia pessoal, minha dúvida hoje é como posso configurar um botão em uma página web para abrir o console (por exemplo, no Chrome é usado a combinação de botões Ctrl+Shift+I). Esse código tem que ser desenvolvido utilizando HTML e JavaScript, pois são as linguagens que estou estudando atualmente.

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível. A bolha de segurança dos navegadores não permite interagir com a aba do console, isso seria uma tremenda falha... Talvez via extensão...

Comment: Especificamente o Chrome, tem uma pergunta no SOen sobre abrir **o devtools**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension (não sei se é considerável, dada a época que foi feita: 2013).  Já sobre o console, o que dá pra fazer é simular o console em algum elemento HTML (semelhante ao snippet aqui do site)...

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pelas informações pessoal.

Answer (score -1):

Não há formas para isso, pois o devtool não é algo para os user utilizar. Não sei ao certo o porque você gostaria de fazer isso, mas não é possível.